# XmlSchemaException C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have to read an XML from file, which is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
   <KyactusProfileClass xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <username>sadasdsad</username> 
      <userid>0067AA87BF9AD466792E1A20F6AAB7F</userid>
      <useDefaultFolder>false</useDefaultFolder>
      <autoAcceptDownloads>false</autoAcceptDownloads>
      <visible>false</visible>
   </KyactusProfileClass>
```

I read it using following code:

```
using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(pathXML))
{
    Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText(pathXML));
    schemas.Add(null, xmlReader);
}
```

But I get following error:

> System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaException: 'The root element of W3C XML Schema must be < schema > and its namesapce must be 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.'

I generated that XML using a XML serializer and XSD Schema validator:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="kyactusprofile" type="kyactusprofile" />
  <xs:complexType name="kyactusprofile" >
    <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="username" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="userid"  maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element type="xs:boolean" name="useDefaultFolder"  maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="defaultFolder"  maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element type="xs:boolean" name="autoAcceptDownloads"  maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element type="xs:boolean" name="visible"  />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

---

Hers is the stack trace:

```
System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaException
  HResult=0x80131941
  Message=L'elemento radice di W3C XML Schema deve essere <schema> e il suo spazio dei nomi deve essere 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.
  Source=System.Xml
  StackTrace:
   at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet.InternalValidationCallback(Object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
   at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet.SendValidationEvent(XmlSchemaException e, XmlSeverityType severity)
   at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet.ParseSchema(String targetNamespace, XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet.Add(String targetNamespace, XmlReader schemaDocument)
   at Kyactus.XmlManager.GestoreXml.ValidateXmlWithXsd(String pathXML) in C:\Users\Cristiano\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\progetto-pds\visual-studio\Kyactus\Kyactus\XmlManager\GestoreXml.cs:line 249
   at Kyactus.XmlManager.GestoreXml.UnmarshallProfile() in C:\Users\Cristiano\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\progetto-pds\visual-studio\Kyactus\Kyactus\XmlManager\GestoreXml.cs:line 178
   at Kyactus.XmlManager.GestoreXml..ctor() in C:\Users\Cristiano\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\progetto-pds\visual-studio\Kyactus\Kyactus\XmlManager\GestoreXml.cs:line 64
   at Kyactus.App..ctor() in C:\Users\Cristiano\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\progetto-pds\visual-studio\Kyactus\Kyactus\App.xaml.cs:line 21
   at Kyactus.App.Main()
```

Comment: If you take off all the `xs:` and remove the `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`, does it work then?

Comment: Please paste error stack trace.

Comment: Are you reading the XML or the XSD with the `XmlReader`?

Comment: @simonalexander2005 I removed xs: and the URL, but the problem persists

Comment: @SebastianHofmann et voila, the stack trace

Comment: @SebastianHofmann I am reading the XML not the XSD, perhaps should be this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are most likely reading the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
   <KyactusProfileClass xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <username>sadasdsad</username> 
      <userid>0067AA87BF9AD466792E1A20F6AAB7F</userid>
      <useDefaultFolder>false</useDefaultFolder>
      <autoAcceptDownloads>false</autoAcceptDownloads>
      <visible>false</visible>
   </KyactusProfileClass>
```

with the `XmlReader` and try to add it as `XmlSchema`. That's the wrong approach, it's not a schema! You have to read your `XSD`, then no `Exception` will appear.

Comment: You're right, I was upstream. I messed up with similar names of XML and XSD files. Now it works.